# Moving elements in an array (checks if 0)

Tags: c

I have to make a function which will check if there are 0 in an array and if there are they are to be moved to the beginning of the array, example **0 4 0 8 9** -> **0 0 4 8 9**, I've tried using this function

```
void movement(int a[],int n)
{    
     int temp,k=0,i;

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(a[i]==0);
        {
           k++;
           a[i]=a[i-1];
        }
        for(i=1;i<k;i++)
        {
            a[i]=0;
        }
    }

}
```

However it doesn't work, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Look into a bubble sort.  It will do exactly what you are trying to do.  Just stop it after all of the zeroes have moved.  Also, go and read the documentation on how to ask a good question here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "it doesn't work" part? *How* doesn't it work? How do you use (and call) this function? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lastly I recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If all you're doing is moving zeros to the beginning and you care not about the order of the remaining elements, this can be done with a single loop and two pointers (a "reader" and a "writer"). Both start at index-0. As you walk the reader up the array, if the value pointed to is zero, swap it with whatever is at the writer position, then bump the writer. Always advance the reader with each iteration, and only advance the writer if you performed a swap. One pass, O(n) complexity.

Comment: @WhozCraig.: 2 color variation of Dutch national flag problem.

Comment: Also `if(a[i]==0);` --> `if(a[i]==0)`

Answer (score 2):

As far as what you say you don't actually need to sort, you only need to move 0s to the beginning of the array.

That being the case just go through the array once, with a teseconindex variable that stores the lowest index that is non-zero. Teach time you find a zero swap the 0 for the item at the stored zero index and increment that as well.

```
for(size_t ndx = 0, zeroNdx = 0; count> ndx; ++ndx)
{
  if(!arr[ndx])

    arr[ndx] = arr[ndxZero];
    arr[ndxZero++] = 0;
  }  {
}
```

If you actually do need to sort this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting elements in between a array is costly so I'm using a temporary array. Here is a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[]={0,1,2,0,3,0,0};
    int temp[100];
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
        if(array[i]==0){
            temp[count]=array[i]; //copy all zero into temp first
            count++;
        }
    }   
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]!=0 && count<=6)
        {

            temp[count]=array[i]; //fill other elements other than 0
             count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",temp[6]);
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
        printf("%d ",temp[i]);
    }
}
```

o/p: 0 0 0 0 1 2 3

Comment: Not sure why this got up-voted, this solution is far too complex & time consuming. If it was used as a function like the OP had designed it'd require a malloc/free to do its job correctly. copying the array is absolutely unneeded.

Comment: why it would need a malloc? I could create temp as the size of main array. Yes I could make a separate function but that isn't necessary as the size is being passed in the argument. And the solution is not complex at all yes I agree it's time consuming but shifting elements in the array is not that much less than that of my solution.

Comment: because as a function you'd have to create your temp[]  array to any size passed as the 'n'  parameter. Additionally, where you're now printing it you'd have to copy the data back to the array passed by the caller. Your algorithm is O(3n)  H.S's answer and my answer are faster and better answers, they're both O(n). I think mine would run a tiny bit faster than HS's but I didn't test that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
void movement(int a[],int n)
{
 int temp,k=0,i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 0)
        {
            if (a[k] == 0)
                    k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (a[k] != 0)
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[k];
                a[k] = temp;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will move all the `0`'s in the array at the begining of array. Complexity - O(n), only one pass through given array and no extra space required.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it with a tiny bit less complexity:

```
void movement(int a[],int n)
{    
     int i,k;

    for(k=0;k<n && a[k]==0;k++);


    for(i=n-1;i>k;i--)
    {
        if(a[i]==0)
        {
          a[i]=a[k];
          a[k++]=0;
        }

    }

}
```